# Fill empty values of a nested array with specific value Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `Action` which receives an array parameter like this.

```
[
  ['X','','O'],
  ['O','','O'],
  ['X','X','']
]
```

I want this function to return an array like this where each empty section of the previous array is filled individually with a specific value, e.g `Y`.

```
[
 [
   ['','Y',''],
   ['','',''],
   ['','','']
 ],
 [
   ['','',''],
   ['','Y',''],
   ['','','']
 ],
 [
   ['','',''],
   ['','',''],
   ['','','Y']
 ]

]
```

I know I can do that with `forEach` but it needs nested `forEach` which I think isn't very optimal. Is there any better way of doing that?

Comment: You forgot to post the code you want help to improve.

Comment: Are the nested arrays always of the same length?  3 arrays by 3 elements? You could potential iterate them at the same time and spare yourself a loop.

Comment: Yes It's always the same length.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let arr = [
  ['X','','O'],
  ['O','','O'],
  ['X','X','']
]

let res = []

arr.map((item, index)=>{
    item.map((sub, indx) =>{
        if(sub === ""){
        let array_=
            [
               ['','',''],
               ['','',''],
               ['','','']
             ];

             array_[index][indx] = "Y";

             res.push(array_)

        }
    })
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid nesting loops with the following steps

- flatten the matrix into a 1-d array
- get the indices of the empty sections
- create new flatten 1-d arrays with empty indices from previous result marked as `'Y'`
- transform flatten 1-d arrays back to 3x3 matrix

```js
const arr = [
  ["X", "", "O"],
  ["O", "", "O"],
  ["X", "X", ""],
]

const res = arr
  .flat() // flatten the array
  .map((section, i) => [section, i])
  .filter(([section, _]) => section === "")
  .map(([_, i]) => i) // get the indices of empty sections
  .map(sectionIdx =>
    Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, i) => (i === sectionIdx ? "Y" : ""))
  ) // create new flattened array with empty indices marked as 'Y'
  .map(flattenedArr => [
    flattenedArr.slice(0, 3),
    flattenedArr.slice(3, 6),
    flattenedArr.slice(6, 9),
  ]) // turn back flatten array into 3x3 matrix

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel compelled to give the trivial answer, which is to continue using nested `.forEach`.  This results in very readable code, which is, in my experience, more valuable than high performance code most of the time.

I'd begin by looping over each row and column of your input.  Every time you encounter an matching cell (i.e. empty string, in your case), clone the input structure (using `.map` to `''`) and replace the matching element with the desired replacement string (e.g. `'Y'`).

```js
const input = [
  ['X','','O'],
  ['O','','O'],
  ['X','X','']
]

const result = [];
input.forEach((row, iRow) => row.forEach((col, iCol) => {
    if (col == '') {
      const clone = input.map(row => row.map(col => ''));
      clone[iRow][iCol] = 'Y';
      result.push(clone);
    }
}));

console.log(result);
```